# How do I prove the partial denominators formula of the Bauer-Muir transformation of a generalized continued fraction?

Tags: number-theory, sequences-and-series, continued-fractions, computational-mathematics

*Notation*: $b_{0}+\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\mathbb{K}}}\left( a_{n}/b_{n}\right) $ is the [Gauss Notation for generalized continued fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_continued_fraction).

---

**Description of the [Bauer-Muir transformation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Bauer-MuirTransformation.html)**

(Based on [pp. 76-77](http://calcauxprobteor.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/cfwa-bmtpdf.pdf) of Lisa Lorentzen and Haakon Waadeland's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444892656) (A), chapter II, theorems 11, and Theorem 7;  also section 5 of J. Mc Laughlin, and Nancy J. Wyshinski's online [paper](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0402/0402462v2.pdf) (C), and section 5 of Bruce C. Berndt, Sen-Shan Huang, Jaebum Sohn, and Seung Hwan Son's online [paper](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/bhss.pdf) (B) ).

Given a convergent c.f. $\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\mathbb{K}}}(a_{n}/b_{n})=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }A_{n}/B_{n}$ and a sequence ${w_{n}}$ we can construct a new c.f $\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\mathbb{K}}}({c_{n}/d_{n}})=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }C_{n}/D_{n}$ (if convergent) which is its *Bauer-Muir transform with respect to* ${w_{n}}$.

By theorem 11, chapter II, of Lisa Lorentzen and Haakon Waadeland's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444892656) (A), [pp.76-77](http://calcauxprobteor.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/cfwa-bmtpdf.pdf), the relations between $A_{n},B_{n}$ and $C_{n},D_{n}$ are given by:

$C_{n}=A_{n}+A_{n-1}w_{n}$, $D_{n}=B_{n}+B_{n-1}w_{n}$, with the initial conditions $C_{-1}=1,D_{-1}=0.$

If for $n\geq 1$,  $\lambda_{n}=a_{n}-w_{n-1}(b_{n}+w_{n})\neq 0$, then

$$c_{n}=a_{n-1}\lambda_{n}/\lambda_{n-1},$$

$$d_{n}=b_{n}+w_{n}-w_{n-2}\lambda_{n}/\lambda _{n-1},$$

for $n\geq 2,$ and

$$\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\mathbb{K}}}(a_{n}/b_{n})=w_{0}+\dfrac{\lambda_{1}}{b_{1}+w_{1}+\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\mathbb{K}}}(c_{n}/d_{n})}.$$

The elements of $\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\mathbb{K}}}(a_{n}/b_{n})$ are computed by an application of Theorem 7, chapter II, of Lisa Lorentzen and Haakon Waadeland's [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444892656) (A), which transforms a sequence into a continued fraction. *I was able to derive* $c_{n}$ *but not* $d_{n}$.

---

**Example:** Application to the $\log (1+t)$ expansion. By choosing $w_{0}=w_{1}=0,w_{n}=(n-1)t$, for $n\geq 2$, one can derive

$$\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\mathbb{K}}}\left( n^{2}t/\left( \left(
n+1\right) -kt\right) \right) =\dfrac{t}{2+\underset{n=3}{\overset{\infty }{%
\mathbb{K}}}\left( \left( n-2\right) ^{2}t/\left( n-\left( n-3\right)
t\right) \right) }.$$

Hence (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm)) the expansion

$$\log (1+t)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}t^{n}}{n}=\dfrac{t}{1+%
\underset{n=1}{\overset{\infty }{\mathbb{K}}}\left( n^{2}t/\left( \left(
n+1\right) -nt\right) \right) },$$

can be improved with respect to the convergence speed to this one

$$\log (1+t)=\dfrac{t}{1+\dfrac{t}{2+\underset{n=3}{\overset{\infty }{\mathbb{%
K}}}\left( \left( n-2\right) ^{2}t/\left( n-\left( n-3\right) t\right)
\right) }}.$$

---

**Derivation of $c_n$**

Here is how I got $c_n$. In page 77 of reference A it is proved that

$$C_{n-1}D_n-D_{n-1}C_n=(A_{n-1}B_{n-2}-A_{n-2}B_{n-1})\lambda_n.$$

Hence

$$C_{n-2}D_{n-1}-D_{n-2}C_{n-1}=(A_{n-2}B_{n-3}-A_{n-3}B_{n-2})\lambda_{n-1}.$$

For $n\ge 2$ Theorem 7 of reference A (derived from the fundamental c.f. recurrence) gives

$$c_n=\dfrac{C_{n-1}D_n-D_{n-1}C_n}{-(C_{n-2}D_{n-1}-D_{n-2}C_{n-1})}=\dfrac{(A_{n-1}B_{n-2}-A_{n-2}B_{n-1})\lambda_n}{-(A_{n-2}B_{n-3}-A_{n-3}B_{n-2})\lambda_{n-1}}.$$

By the determinant formula we have

$$A_{n-1}B_{n-2}-A_{n-2}B_{n-1}=-a_{n-1}(A_{n-2}B_{n-3}-A_{n-3}B_{n-2}).$$

Thus

$$c_n=a_{n-1}\dfrac{\lambda_n}{\lambda_{n-1}}.$$

---

> **QUESTION 1: How does one prove**
>
> $$d_{n}=b_{n}+w_{n}-w_{n-2}\lambda_{n}/\lambda_{n-1}$$
>
> **from**
>
> $$d_{n}=\dfrac{C_{n}D_{n-2}-D_{n}C_{n-2}}{C_{n}D_{n-1}-D_{n}C_{n-1}}\qquad\text{for}\quad n\ge 2$$
>
> **and**
>
> $\lambda_{n}=a_{n}-w_{n-1}(b_{n}+w_{n})$,
>   $C_{n}=A_{n}+A_{n-1}w_{n}$,
>   $D_{n}=B_{n}+B_{n-1}w_{n}$ **?**

---

**References**

A - Lisa Lorentzen and Haakon Waadeland, *[Continued Fractions and Applications](http://calcauxprobteor.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/cfwa-bmtpdf.pdf)*, North-Holland, Amsterdam, 1992. ([pdf file of pp. 76-77](http://calcauxprobteor.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/cfwa-bmtpdf.pdf))

B - Bruce C. Berndt, Sen-Shan Huang, Jaebum Sohn, and Seung Hwan Son, *[A Transformation Formula in Rogers--Ramanujan Continued Fraction](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~berndt/articles/bhss.pdf)*. (section 5)

C - J. Mc Laughlin, and Nancy J. Wyshinski, *[Real numbers with polynomial continued fraction expansions](http://arxiv.org/PS_cache/math/pdf/0402/0402462v2.pdf)*, arXiv, 2004.

Comment: well thats over my head

Comment: I think you could shunt this over to mathoverflow

Comment: This sort of question looks like nobody will answer it unless they're right in the trenches studying this theory as they read it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to Question 1:

Using the following relations (in Perron, *Die Lehre von den Kettenbrüchen*, Band II, 1957 and Sergey Khrushchev, *Orthogonal Polynomials and
Continued Fractions: From Euler's Point of View*, 2008)

$$\begin{equation}
A_{n}B_{n-1}-A_{n-1}B_{n}=\left( -1\right) ^{n-1}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n} 
\nonumber
\end{equation}$$

$$\begin{equation}
A_{n}B_{n-2}-A_{n-2}B_{n}=\left( -1\right) ^{n}b_{n}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n-1}
\end{equation}$$

$$\begin{equation}
A_{n}B_{n-3}-A_{n-3}B_{n }=(-1)^{n-1}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n -2}\left(
b_{n}b_{n-1}+a_{n}\right)   
\end{equation}$$

we can derive

$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left( A_{n}+w_{n}A_{n-1}\right) \left( B_{n-1}+w_{n-1}B_{n-2}\right)   \\
&&-\left( A_{n-1}+w_{n-1}A_{n-2}\right) \left( B_{n}+w_{n}B_{n-1}\right)  \\
&=&-\left( -1\right) ^{n }a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n-1}\left(
a_{v}-w_{n-1}\left( b_{n}+w_{n}\right) \right)   
\end{eqnarray}$$

and

$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left( A_{n -1}+w_{n-1}A_{n-2}\right) \left(
B_{n-2}+w_{n-2}B_{n-3}\right)   \nonumber \\
&&-\left( A_{n-3}+w_{n-3}A_{\nu -3}\right) \left( B_{n-1}+w_{n-1}B_{n
-2}\right)    \\
&=&-\left( -1\right) ^{n -1}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n-2}\left(
a_{n-1}-w_{n-2}\left( b_{n-1}+w_{n-1}\right) \right)   
\end{eqnarray}$$

as well as

$$\begin{eqnarray}
&&\left( A_{n}+w_{n}A_{n-1}\right) (B_{n-2}+w_{n-2}B_{n-3})   \\
&&-(A_{n-2}+w_{n-2}A_{n-3})\left( B_{n}+w_{n}B_{n -1}\right)    \\
&=&\left( -1\right) ^{n}b_{n }a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n -1}+w_{n
-2}(-1)^{n -1}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n -2}\left( b_{n}b_{n-1}+a_{n}\right) 
 \\
&&+w_{n}\left( -1\right) ^{n -2}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n-1}+w_{n-2}\left(
-1\right) ^{n-1}b_{n-1}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n-2} 
\end{eqnarray}$$

Therefore

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
d_{n} &=&\frac{\left( A_{n}+w_{n}A_{n-1}\right)
(B_{n-2}+w_{n-2}B_{n-3})-(A_{n-2}+w_{n-2}A_{n-3})\left(
B_{n}+w_{n}B_{n-1}\right) }{%
(A_{n-1}+w_{n-1}A_{n-2})(B_{n-2}+w_{n-2}B_{n-3})-(A_{n-2}+w_{n-2}A_{n-3})(B_{n-1}+w_{n-1}B_{n-2})%
} \\
&=&\frac{\left( -1\right) ^{n}b_{n}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots
a_{n-1}+w_{n-2}(-1)^{n-1}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n-2}\left(
b_{n}b_{n-1}+a_{n}\right) }{-\left( -1\right) ^{n -1}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots
a_{n-2}\left( a_{n-1}-w_{n-2}\left( b_{n -1}+w_{n-1}\right) \right) } \\
&&+\frac{w_{n }\left( -1\right) ^{n-2}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots
a_{n-1}+w_{n-2}\left( -1\right) ^{n-1}b_{n -1}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n-2}}{%
-\left( -1\right) ^{n-1}a_{1}a_{2}\cdots a_{n-2}\left( a_{v-1}-w_{n-2}\left(
b_{n-1}+r_{n-1}\right) \right) } \\
&=&\dfrac{\left( b_{n}+w_{n}\right) \left(
a_{n-1}-w_{n-2}(b_{n-1}+w_{n-1})\right) -w_{n-2}\left(
a_{n}-w_{n-1}(b_{n}+w_{n})\right) }{a_{n-1}-w_{n-2}(b_{n-1}+w_{n-1})} \\
&=&b_{n }+w_{n}-w_{n-2}\dfrac{a_{n }-w_{n-1}(b_{n }+w_{n})}{a_{n
-1}-w_{n-2}(b_{n-1}+w_{n-1})}
\end{eqnarray*}$$

This transformation appears also in "Die Transformation von Bauer und Muir", §7 of Oskar Perron, *Die Lehre von den Kettenbrüchen*, Band II, 1957.