# Continued fraction inequality with well know constant as $\pi$ and golden ratio.

Tags: inequality, closed-form, continued-fractions, constants

I found this inequality beautiful let me share it  :

Let :

$$d=\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{1+\frac{2a^{2}}{1+\frac{3a^{3}}{1+\cdot\cdot\cdot}}}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{b}{1+\frac{2b^{2}}{1+\frac{3b^{3}}{1+\cdot\cdot\cdot}}}},a=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2},b=\frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$$

Then :

$$\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{1+\frac{2a^{2}}{1+\frac{3a^{3}}{1+\cdot\cdot\cdot}}}}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{b}{1+\frac{2b^{2}}{1+\frac{3b^{3}}{1+\cdot\cdot\cdot}}}}\right)^2<\pi-\ln\pi$$

I have knowledge of continued fractions so if you could provide me with some hint(s), that would be preferable .

Let $v$ as in my comment below then it seems we have :

$$|r-t|<d^2-\pi+\ln\pi$$

Where $r$ is the expression $v$ with the value $a=\sqrt{5}$ and $t$ the value $a=\sqrt{\pi/4}$.

Remark :

It might be interesting to evaluate the odd and even case I mean the difference so the two differences in $v$ expression perhaps it's equal... to $0$

How do I show this? Do we have a closed form expression for $d$?

Comment: It is relatively simple to compute if we first expand the numerator

Comment: I finally found this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogers%E2%80%93Ramanujan_continued_fraction

Comment: What does it give ? (I am unable to read it- too many symbols)

Comment: And https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4626/how-do-i-prove-the-partial-denominators-formula-of-the-bauer-muir-transformation

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici it's a start nothing else.As I said l' m a beginner in that domain.

Comment: Now, we are two ! Let us find two more and let us play bridge. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I cannot read and plays bridge simultanetly .See  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40598-021-00190-y

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144695/discussion-between-erik-satie-and-claude-leibovici).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just computing the numbers for
$$d=\big(f(a)+f(b)\big)^2$$ Using $1000$ levels, the numerical values are
$$f(a)=0.70971940484203666255310483661179592566676895106748$$
$$f(b)=0.69762814978893353418889274755209993243313281242287$$
$$d=1.9806271395257716424616215274705710807886558152997$$

which is much smaller than $\pi-\log(\pi)$  (the difference is $\sim 0.016235$)

None of these numbers has been recognized by the inverse symbolic calculators I tried.

However, searching for a simple approximation
$$\color{blue}{\large d \sim \pi-\log(\pi)-\frac 1{10 e}\Omega ^{\sqrt[3]{3}}}$$ which is
$\color{red}{1.9806271}408$

Comment: We have : $$v=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{a}{1+\frac{a^{2}}{1+\frac{a^{3}}{1+\cdot\cdot\cdot}}}},u=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{b}{1+\frac{b^{2}}{1+\cdot\cdot\cdot}}},b=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2},a=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$ then : $$\left(u-v\right)^{2}+\left(d\right)^{2}\simeq 2$$ . i found this problem nightmarish.

Comment: @ErikSatie $1.990264695$

Comment: I find this one nice $$d^{1.675}-\sqrt{\pi}\simeq 0$$

Comment: $d=f(a)+f(b)$..my bad

Comment: Use in v ,$a=\sqrt{5},a=\sqrt{\pi/4}$ You would be surprised...:-).